# How do you cause an iOS app to enter suspend state to test background task behaviour?

Tags: ios

To QA an app that runs in the background, I would like to be able to cause it to enter the suspend state.  Is there a reliable way to trigger this?

Comment: Press your device's home button will put your app in background without stopping the debugger. Can't you use this method to test your app ?

Comment: That defeats the whole point of continuous integration and automated testing...

Comment: @Yaman - I think the background state and the suspended state are different.  See the diagram here https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH2-SW3

Comment: @Robert You are correct. 'Background' and 'suspended' are two different states. If an app is in background and not suspended, it can execute code. A suspended app cannot execute any code. I still don't know how i can move my app into suspended mode for testing a specific use case.

Comment: However, if I open a dozen other random applications, iOS moves my app into a suspended state. Hope this helps

Answer (score 3):

If you want to run automated tests that put your app in the background, you're going to want to use UIAutomation.  You can specifically look at [UIATarget.deactivateAppForDuration()](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/ToolsLanguages/Reference/UIATargetClassReference/UIATargetClass/UIATargetClass.html#//apple_ref/javascript/instm/UIATarget/deactivateAppForDuration), which will accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Just open an external URL and your app will move to the background in favor of Safari:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://www.google.com"]];
```

**Edit:**
I've never used UIAutomation before, but looking at things I think KevinH's answer should be better for your case.